# How to import MarkerClusterer from react google maps instead of require

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

In the example they use `const { MarkerClusterer } = require("react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer");` , but I want to use import.

I tried using

`import { MarkerClusterer } from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer';`

This did not seem to work for me, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It worked for me:

`import { default as MarkerClusterer } from "react-google-maps/lib/components/addons/MarkerClusterer";`